# How do I set the proxy-url for gcp cluster in shell?

Tags: ruby, shell, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run this command in a shell file via a ruby project in gitlab pipeline.

```
kubectl config set clusters."$Cluster_config".insecure-skip-tls-verify true
kubectl config set clusters."$Cluster_config".proxy-url http://myserver.com:3128
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Property "clusters.gke_myserver_europe-west1_ser-dev-cluster.insecure-skip-tls-verify" set.
error: can't set a map to a value: map[gke_myserver_europe-west1_ser-dev-cluster:0xc0000e2ae0]
```

Do you have any suggestion what is wrong?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you string quote the proxy URL? e.g., `kubectl config set clusters."$Cluster_config".proxy-url "http://myserver.com:3128"`

Comment: @anothermh: we tried it didn't work.
we tried these options:
1- use a variable instead of url,
2-use double quote

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the kubectl version on that specific image I was using was old, so by updating that problem solved.